# Как сделать, чтобы шкала Progress Bar падала каждую секунду?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Как сделать так, чтобы шкала прогресса бара в Android Studio уменьшалась, к примеру, каждую секунду на одну единицу?

Comment: ваш вопрос на самом деле состоит из двух: 1. Как сделать что-либо через промежуток времени. 2. Как изменить прогресс у `ProgressBar`, и ответы на оба эти вопроса можно найти секунд эдак за 18 в гугле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант №1

Используете [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
ProgressBar mProgressBar;
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
int i=0;

mProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
   mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.v("Log_tag", "Здесь фиксируется каждая секунда"+ i+ millisUntilFinished);
            i++;
            mProgressBar.setProgress(i);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        // Здесь заканчивается 5 секунд
            i++;
            mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
        }
    };
    mCountDownTimer.start();
```

---

Вариант №2

1. Создаете AsyncTask или другой вид потока.
2. Создаете цикл, который заканчивается когда ваша задача закончилась
3. В цикле делаете задержку в минуту и меняете значения progress bar